# Try to make HTTP request in TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, api, http, textwatcher

There is an edit text field where user insert text. After some delay programm has to send HTTP request to get JSON object. All methods which works with HTTP request works well because in previous version all requests were sent by push the button. Now i  want to remove "SEND" button and want programm send requests by itself. But i got an error. Need to understand how i need to modify the code to start it work correctly.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AppCompatButton translateButton;
    AppCompatButton chooseLanguageButton;
    AppCompatEditText translatedTextOutput;
    AppCompatEditText translatedTextInput;
    String translatedInputString;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";
    final String TAG = "myTag";

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Timer timer;

    private TextWatcher searchTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sendJsonRequest();
                }
            }, 600);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        translateButton = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        chooseLanguageButton = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.choose_language_button);
        translatedTextOutput = (AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.translated_text_field);
        translatedTextInput = (AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.translation_input_edit);
        translatedTextInput.addTextChangedListener(searchTextWatcher);

        translateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Inside onClick");
                requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                sendJsonRequest();
            }
        });

        chooseLanguageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveText();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChooseLanguageList.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        loadText();
    }

    void saveText() {
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, translatedTextInput.getText().toString());
        ed.commit();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Text saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    void loadText() {
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
        translatedTextInput.setText(savedText);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Text loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public void sendJsonRequest() {
        Intent myIntent = getIntent();
        String language = myIntent.getStringExtra("short");
        Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "language short = " + language);
        translatedInputString = translatedTextInput.getText().toString();
        String url = String.format(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.request_template),
                String.format(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.query_Template), translatedInputString, language ));
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Inside OnResponse" + response.toString());
                JSONArray results = null;
                try {
                    results = response.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("translations");
                    for (int i=0,j=results.length();i<j;i++) {
                        String webTitle = results.getJSONObject(i).getString("translatedText");
                        translatedTextOutput.setText(webTitle);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error :" + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "NetworkError");
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!");
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "AuthFailureError");
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!");
                } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "NoConnectionError!");
                } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.");
                }
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }

}
```

The error code is

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
    Process: com.borisruzanov.volleyexample, PID: 3630
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
    at com.borisruzanov.volleyexample.MainActivity.sendJsonRequest(MainActivity.java:167)
    at com.borisruzanov.volleyexample.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:58)
    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
    W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe975ad80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    I/Choreographer: Skipped 114 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xeae69c70
    E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xeae69ce0

    [ 11-01 14:58:12.135   936:  948 D/         ]
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd8bbab70, tid 948
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you create the `RequestQueue` only when `translateButton` is clicked.
Move this line outside the `OnClickListener`:

`requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);`

Also consider using Singleton Pattern as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html) recommends.

Comment: Thank you that helped. I knew that I missed something like this. But couldn't find it